# skipping a match in regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract some number value from a text. Skipping is done based on a matching text.
For example :

```
      Input Text - 
      ABC Company Export Items 4 Bought by XYZ Amount 400.00 with GST# 36479 GST percentage is 20%.
      OR
      ABC Company Export Items 4 Bought by XYZ Amount 400.00 with GST Reg No. 36479 GST% is 20%.
      OR
      ABC Company Export Items 4 Bought by XYZ Amount 400.00 with GST Reg# 36479 GST% is 20%.

      Output Text -
      Amount 400.00
      GST 36479
      GST 20%
```

Main point is input text can be in any format but output text should be same. One thing that will be same is GST Number will be non-decimal number, GST percentage will be number followed by "%" symbol and amount will be in decimal form.

I tried but not able to skip the non-numeric value after GST. Please help.

What I tried :

```
              pattern = re.compile(r"\b(?<=GST).\D(\d+)")
```

Comment: Try `\bGST\D*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%?)`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vs7lSM/2). Or, `\bAmount\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?).*?\bGST\D*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%?).*?\bGST\D*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%?)` (see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vs7lSM/3)).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, but this is not skipping the non-numeric value after GST. Like I mentioned in Output Text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
\bAmount\s*(?P<amount>\d+(?:\.\d+)?).*?\bGST\D*(?P<gst_id>\d+(?:\.\d+)?).*?\bGST\D*(?P<gst_prcnt>\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vs7lSM/4). *Details*:

- `\bAmount\s*` - a whole word `Amount` and zero or more whitespaces
- `(?P<amount>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group "amount": one or more digits and then an optional sequence of `.` and one or more digits
- `.*?` - some text (excluding whitespace)
- `\bGST` - a word `GST`
- `\D*` - **zero or more chars other than digits**
- `(?P<gst_id>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group "gst_id": one or more digits and then an optional sequence of `.` and one or more digits
- `.*?` - some text (excluding whitespace)
- `\bGST\D*` - a word `GST` and then zero or more chars other than digits
- `(?P<gst_prcnt>\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)` - Group "gst_prcnt": one or more digits and then an optional sequence of `.` and one or more digits, and then a `%` char.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/lfNqLt):

```py
import re
pattern = r"\bAmount\s*(?P<amount>\d+(?:\.\d+)?).*?\bGST\D*(?P<gst_id>\d+(?:\.\d+)?).*?\bGST\D*(?P<gst_prcnt>\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)"

texts = ["ABC Company Export Items 4 Bought by XYZ Amount 400.00 with GST# 36479 GST percentage is 20%.",
"ABC Company Export Items 4 Bought by XYZ Amount 400.00 with GST Reg No. 36479 GST% is 20%.",
"ABC Company Export Items 4 Bought by XYZ Amount 400.00 with GST Reg# 36479 GST% is 20%."]

for text in texts:
    m = re.search(pattern, text)
    if m:
        print(m.groupdict())
```

Output:

```
{'amount': '400.00', 'gst_id': '36479', 'gst_prcnt': '20%'}
{'amount': '400.00', 'gst_id': '36479', 'gst_prcnt': '20%'}
{'amount': '400.00', 'gst_id': '36479', 'gst_prcnt': '20%'}
```